# Angles and secants in an ellipse

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Can I express $\gamma$ as an analytic function of $a,b,c$, and $\alpha$?

[image]

So far, I have computing $p_1$ from $a,b,\alpha$, then solved numerically for $p_2$ by intersecting the ellipse with a circle with radius $c$, then solved analytically for $\gamma$ using $\alpha, a,b$ and $p_2$. I am looking for a better way that, ideally, does not require a numerical solver in the middle.

Comment: Which tools did you draw your diagram with?

Comment: powerpoint. why?

Comment: That's impressive. I wasn't aware something as accessible as PowerPoint could do this. I've been looking for a good drawing tool for making some notes with.

Comment: That's impressive. I wasn't aware something as accessible as PowerPoint could do this. I've been looking for a good drawing tool for making some notes with.

Comment: Are you interested in Groebner bases solver solutions?  I have used it on things like this.  Basically you feed it a set of algebraic equations and it finds the simultaneous equations in to a lower triangular of equations that are the result.  You walk your way up the ladder one parameter at a time until you have the final solution.  There is a problem that angles have to be interpreted algebraically; say s=cos(\alpha), t=sin(\theta) , and the answer is arcsin(t).   If you want I will do that as an answer (to keep in practice) ; but I am sure it wouldn't get credit as homework solution :)

Answer (score 1):

The intersection of circle and ellipse generates quartic equation. The quartic equation is solvable in algebraic functions, so the answer to your question is yes, there is an analytic solution. however the resulting formula is so big, that a Brent or even Newton method would work way faster.

To illustrate what we are talking about. Here is the answer to one of the coordinate of an equivalent problem of 
$$
\begin{cases}
a x^2+bxy+cy^2=1,\\
(x-1)^2+y^2=1
\end{cases}
$$
$$
x=\frac{b^2+2 c^2-2 a c}{2 \left(a^2-2 c a+b^2+c^2\right)}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\left(b^2+2 c^2-2 a c\right)^2}{\left(a^2-2 c
   a+b^2+c^2\right)^2}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{128 c^6-384 c^5+384 a c^4+384 c^4-288 b^2 c^3-768 a c^3-128 c^3+384 a^2 c^2+432 b^2 c^2+384 a
   c^2-384 a^2 c-288 a b^2 c-144 b^2 c+108 b^4+128 a^3+144 a b^2+\sqrt{11664 b^8-6912 c^3 b^6+10368 c^2 b^6+31104 a b^6-62208 a c
   b^6+10368 c b^6-6912 b^6+27648 a c^4 b^4-6912 c^4 b^4+27648 a^3 b^4-55296 a c^3 b^4+13824 c^3 b^4-6912 a^2 b^4+55296 a^2 c^2
   b^4+13824 a c^2 b^4-6912 c^2 b^4-55296 a^2 c b^4+13824 a c b^4}}}{3 \sqrt[3]{2} \left(a^2-2 c a+b^2+c^2\right)}+\frac{4
   \sqrt[3]{2} \left(4 c^4-8 c^3+8 a c^2+4 c^2-6 b^2 c-8 a c+4 a^2+3 b^2\right)}{3 \left(a^2-2 c a+b^2+c^2\right) \sqrt[3]{128
   c^6-384 c^5+384 a c^4+384 c^4-288 b^2 c^3-768 a c^3-128 c^3+384 a^2 c^2+432 b^2 c^2+384 a c^2-384 a^2 c-288 a b^2 c-144 b^2 c+108
   b^4+128 a^3+144 a b^2+\sqrt{11664 b^8-6912 c^3 b^6+10368 c^2 b^6+31104 a b^6-62208 a c b^6+10368 c b^6-6912 b^6+27648 a c^4
   b^4-6912 c^4 b^4+27648 a^3 b^4-55296 a c^3 b^4+13824 c^3 b^4-6912 a^2 b^4+55296 a^2 c^2 b^4+13824 a c^2 b^4-6912 c^2 b^4-55296
   a^2 c b^4+13824 a c b^4}}}+\frac{4 \left(-2 c^2-c+a\right)}{3 \left(a^2-2 c a+b^2+c^2\right)}}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{2
   \left(b^2+2 c^2-2 a c\right)^2}{\left(a^2-2 c a+b^2+c^2\right)^2}-\frac{\sqrt[3]{128 c^6-384 c^5+384 a c^4+384 c^4-288 b^2
   c^3-768 a c^3-128 c^3+384 a^2 c^2+432 b^2 c^2+384 a c^2-384 a^2 c-288 a b^2 c-144 b^2 c+108 b^4+128 a^3+144 a b^2+\sqrt{11664
   b^8-6912 c^3 b^6+10368 c^2 b^6+31104 a b^6-62208 a c b^6+10368 c b^6-6912 b^6+27648 a c^4 b^4-6912 c^4 b^4+27648 a^3 b^4-55296 a
   c^3 b^4+13824 c^3 b^4-6912 a^2 b^4+55296 a^2 c^2 b^4+13824 a c^2 b^4-6912 c^2 b^4-55296 a^2 c b^4+13824 a c b^4}}}{3 \sqrt[3]{2}
   \left(a^2-2 c a+b^2+c^2\right)}-\frac{4 \sqrt[3]{2} \left(4 c^4-8 c^3+8 a c^2+4 c^2-6 b^2 c-8 a c+4 a^2+3 b^2\right)}{3
   \left(a^2-2 c a+b^2+c^2\right) \sqrt[3]{128 c^6-384 c^5+384 a c^4+384 c^4-288 b^2 c^3-768 a c^3-128 c^3+384 a^2 c^2+432 b^2
   c^2+384 a c^2-384 a^2 c-288 a b^2 c-144 b^2 c+108 b^4+128 a^3+144 a b^2+\sqrt{11664 b^8-6912 c^3 b^6+10368 c^2 b^6+31104 a
   b^6-62208 a c b^6+10368 c b^6-6912 b^6+27648 a c^4 b^4-6912 c^4 b^4+27648 a^3 b^4-55296 a c^3 b^4+13824 c^3 b^4-6912 a^2
   b^4+55296 a^2 c^2 b^4+13824 a c^2 b^4-6912 c^2 b^4-55296 a^2 c b^4+13824 a c b^4}}}-\frac{\frac{8 \left(b^2+2 c^2-2 a
   c\right)^3}{\left(a^2-2 c a+b^2+c^2\right)^3}+\frac{16 \left(-2 c^2-c+a\right) \left(b^2+2 c^2-2 a c\right)}{\left(a^2-2 c
   a+b^2+c^2\right)^2}+\frac{32 c}{a^2-2 c a+b^2+c^2}}{4 \sqrt{\frac{\left(b^2+2 c^2-2 a c\right)^2}{\left(a^2-2 c
   a+b^2+c^2\right)^2}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{128 c^6-384 c^5+384 a c^4+384 c^4-288 b^2 c^3-768 a c^3-128 c^3+384 a^2 c^2+432 b^2 c^2+384 a
   c^2-384 a^2 c-288 a b^2 c-144 b^2 c+108 b^4+128 a^3+144 a b^2+\sqrt{11664 b^8-6912 c^3 b^6+10368 c^2 b^6+31104 a b^6-62208 a c
   b^6+10368 c b^6-6912 b^6+27648 a c^4 b^4-6912 c^4 b^4+27648 a^3 b^4-55296 a c^3 b^4+13824 c^3 b^4-6912 a^2 b^4+55296 a^2 c^2
   b^4+13824 a c^2 b^4-6912 c^2 b^4-55296 a^2 c b^4+13824 a c b^4}}}{3 \sqrt[3]{2} \left(a^2-2 c a+b^2+c^2\right)}+\frac{4
   \sqrt[3]{2} \left(4 c^4-8 c^3+8 a c^2+4 c^2-6 b^2 c-8 a c+4 a^2+3 b^2\right)}{3 \left(a^2-2 c a+b^2+c^2\right) \sqrt[3]{128
   c^6-384 c^5+384 a c^4+384 c^4-288 b^2 c^3-768 a c^3-128 c^3+384 a^2 c^2+432 b^2 c^2+384 a c^2-384 a^2 c-288 a b^2 c-144 b^2 c+108
   b^4+128 a^3+144 a b^2+\sqrt{11664 b^8-6912 c^3 b^6+10368 c^2 b^6+31104 a b^6-62208 a c b^6+10368 c b^6-6912 b^6+27648 a c^4
   b^4-6912 c^4 b^4+27648 a^3 b^4-55296 a c^3 b^4+13824 c^3 b^4-6912 a^2 b^4+55296 a^2 c^2 b^4+13824 a c^2 b^4-6912 c^2 b^4-55296
   a^2 c b^4+13824 a c b^4}}}+\frac{4 \left(-2 c^2-c+a\right)}{3 \left(a^2-2 c a+b^2+c^2\right)}}}+\frac{8 \left(-2
   c^2-c+a\right)}{3 \left(a^2-2 c a+b^2+c^2\right)}}
$$